# Python code throws error while running in Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio

I am absolutely new to Python. I tried running this code

```
someone = 'Lovegood'
print (someone)
```

And I am getting this error

**Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
NameError: name 'someone' is not defined****

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Are you sure you saved the file with the code?

Comment: That worked. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether you have selected a python interpreter in the visual studio or not. Also, make sure to save the file with a .py extension.

Comment: The error message comes from the Python interpreter, though. So chances are that the interpreter has been selected correctly